# Svg and buttons

Tags: html, css, button, svg

I have this SVG of the world map:

http://codepen.io/itailitai/pen/ZOpJWJ

and this CSS:

```
.worldmap {

  margin: 0 auto;
   background-color:#091e2e;

}
```

I was wondering, Can I make the circles filled with white a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can greatly - and I mean ***greatly*** - simplify your SVG by using the `<circle>` element, eg.

```
<circle cx="20" cy="20" r="8" />
```

It's worth doing this because the cubic-bezier paths that you currently have (presumably generated by your editor) are not accurate circles - you cannot represent a circle as a bezier curve for the same reason you can't represent it as a polygon, it would need infinite sides/curves.

Now that your SVG is about a thousand times smaller, you can actually work with it. Your browser can too, as it will load and render many, many times faster now that it doesn't need to calculate thousands of bezier curves.

SVG elements are... elements! This means that JavaScript and CSS can work with them.

I've made a very crude demo [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NrRvRN), the important bits being:

```css
[fill=white] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```js
var white = document.querySelectorAll("[fill=white]");
var l = white.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
 white[i].onclick = function() {alert(this.id);};
}
```

This very basic code gives the "pointer" cursor to the white circles, and alerts their ID when you click on them.

Depending on your needs, you can build on this however you like.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi again, I'm trying to create a tooltip whenever I hover over a white circle.

Something like this:

http://i.imgur.com/qc0kspf.png

Can you help me with that one?

Comment: You can define your tooltip with an SVG path and `<text>` element. I notice you have a `<g>` for your white circles, so you could put the tooltip in there and define CSS for: `.tooltip {display:none} g>.tooltip {display:block}` to get the hover effect perhaps.